# Making a get request multiple times in a for loop passing in different arguments returns a promise, why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, es6-promise

I use React and promises and I have a 2 functions. The first one returns me data. That data I use when I call my second function - in which I am making a get request (/calling a function where I am making the actual get request). I have to call the second function as many times as the number of items I get in my response from my 1st function.

For example: In my 1st function I get back the following:

response from calling multiAirports function:

```
{Airports: Array(4), Rail stations: Array(0), Others: Array(4), Links: Array(2)}
```

In detailer response.Airports:

```
Array(4) 0:{code: "JFK", name: "John F. Kennedy International Airport"}
1:{code: "LGA", name: "LaGuardia Airport"}
2:{code: "EWR", name: "Newark Liberty International Airport"}
3:{code: "SWF", name: "Stewart International Airport"}
```

Now in my second (anyDestinationData) function, the first argument is the airport code. Here I have 4 airport codes (which Im getting in my response from my first function). Now I need to call anyDestinationDat 4 times with 4 diff. airport codes. Then I would store the data (set state as I'm using react). I am not sure how to do this and keep getting back [promise].

```
import {anyDestinationData} from ...;
import {multipleAirports} from ...;

handleInput() {
    multipleAirports(this.state.input.origin.value).then(response => {
        var result = [];
        var input = this.state.input;
        for (var i = 0; i < response.Airports.length; i++) {
anyDestinationData(response.Airports[i].code, input.departuredate, input.returndate, input.maxfare))
            result.push(
            return anyDestinationData(response.Airports[i].code, input.departuredate, input.returndate, input.maxfare)
        )
        }
        return result;
    }).then(response => {
         this.setState({
           data: response
         })
    })
}
```

In anyDestinationData function is where I am falling my function where I'm making the get request.

Comment: anyDestinationData is returning a promise i suppose. Please include its implementation

Comment: `result.push(return anyDestinationData(…))` is not valid syntax.

Comment: Use `Promise.all` on the `result` which is an array of promises.

Comment: Thank you, with promise.all, it works now and yes the return was wrong before too! Can I ask you why Im getting a promise each time I call the anyDestinationData function?Is it because its part of the promise from before when I call the multipleAirports function?

Comment: You can ask why you're getting a promise each time from `anyDestinationData` each time but since that code is not in your question I'm not sure how you can expect anyone to answer that. Also use @someuser if you want to direct the question to someone.